# How to Compile React-Relay

Tags: reactjs, npm, relayjs, relay, react-relay

I am trying to follow [the official Relay documentation here](https://relay.dev/docs/getting-started/step-by-step-guide/).

After installing React-Relay:

```
npm install --save relay-runtime react-relay
npm install --save-dev relay-compiler graphql babel-plugin-relay
```

... and configuring package.json:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "start": "npm run relay && react-scripts start",
    "build": "npm run relay && react-scripts build",
    "relay": "npm run relay-compiler --schema schema.graphql --src ./src/ --watchman false $@"
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

when I ran:

```
npm start
```

I got the following error:

```
> test@0.1.0 start D:\xampp\htdocs\my-react\test
> npm run relay && react-scripts start


> test@0.1.0 relay D:\xampp\htdocs\my-react\test
> npm run relay-compiler --schema schema.graphql --src ./src/ --watchman false $@

npm ERR! missing script: relay-compiler
```

How can I correctly run relay-compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I must remove 'npm run' in the last line of package.json:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "start": "npm run relay && react-scripts start",
    "build": "npm run relay && react-scripts build",
    "relay": "relay-compiler --schema schema.graphql --src ./src/ --watchman false $@"
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```